# PayPal return URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

In continuation with my pay pal questions...
I have been able to add the pay pal functionality to my website and here are the sequence of steps (I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and C#):

1. User logs into my website
2. Selects products
3. Clicks the PayPal BuyNow button and he is redirected to paypal website where he pays the amount
4. After payment, using the paypal's auto return functionality I have to redirect to a different page on my website where the user has to fill up a questionnaire and I save the questionnaire info against the user name in the database. The questionnaire is necessary.

How can i do step 4. I am just confused on how can I know the user name in the questionnaire page. 
The way I plan to do is in the questionnaire page I will ask the user to enter the user name and password again. is there a better approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am just confused on how can I know the user name in the questionnaire page

If you use [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) the username is stored in an encrypted cookie so you have access to it on all your pages. So inside the controller action which you are using to redirect to after PayPal:

```
public ActionResult SuccessPayment()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name;
    ...
}
```

> The way I plan to do is in the questionnaire page I will ask the user
>   to enter the user name and password again

IMHO that would piss your users off.